# Using debounce function in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I use underscore.js to run task.

```
_.debounce(task, 100)
```

How stop executing `_.debounce`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.debounce` does not execute anything, so you cannot stop it. It **returns** a new function which takes care of the debouncing.

If you don't want to use it anymore, just use the original function.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce) for more information.

Comment: Once the generated debounced method is called you can consider it running until the timeout completes. The question seems about interrupting this and cancel the call that will be debounced because the generated method has been called (but not yet executed the original method).

Comment: @paulT: maybe, maybe not. The question is not very clear IMO.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right. Its a bit ambiguous. I got on this page with my own interpretation in mind and left a comment from this perspective and might have been too quick in concluding so.

Comment: I mean, I understand you point and it makes sense as well. But I guess since the question is 3 years old we will never know for sure :-/

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to slow down an expensive task, i've written [a post here](http://jules.boussekeyt.org/2012/backbonejs-debounce.html) to explain the `_.debounce()` method behaviour.

Cheers

PS....[archived post](http://web.archive.org/web/20131212212604/http://jules.boussekeyt.org/2012/backbonejs-debounce.html)

Comment: The link to your post seems to be dead