# How to cancel a debounced function after it is called and before it executes?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I create a debounced version of a function with underscore:

```
var debouncedThing = _.debounce(thing, 1000);
```

Once debouncedThing is called...

```
debouncedThing();
```

...is there any way to cancel it, during the wait period before it actually executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using debounce function in underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026000/using-debounce-function-in-underscore)

Comment: That question is unclear.  Mine is specific.  That question does not provide an answer to my question.

Comment: Sure you can implement your own version of debouncer that will somehow expose `timeout` or a function clearing the timeout.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you use the last version of lodash you can simply do:

```
// create debounce
const debouncedThing = _.debounce(thing, 1000);

// execute debounce, it will wait one second before executing thing
debouncedThing();

// will cancel the execution of thing if executed before 1 second
debouncedThing.cancel()
```

Another solution is with a flag:

```
// create the flag
let executeThing = true;

const thing = () => {
   // use flag to allow execution cancelling
   if (!executeThing) return false;
   ...
};

// create debounce
const debouncedThing = _.debounce(thing, 1000);

// execute debounce, it will wait one second before executing thing
debouncedThing();

// it will prevent to execute thing content
executeThing = false;
```

Comment: Underscore has been supporting the `.cancel()` method since version 1.9.0.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else using React with state hooks. Wrap the debounce event in a ref to then access elsewhere:

```
const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = React.useState<string>('')
    
const debouncedSearch = React.useRef(
    debounce((textInputValue) => {
        performSearch(textInputValue)
    }, 300),
).current

React.useEffect(() => {
    // cancel any previous debounce action (so that a slower - but later - request doesn't overtake a newer but faster request)
    debouncedSearch.cancel()
    if (textInputValue !== '') {
        debouncedSearch(textInputValue)
    }
}, [textInputValue])
```

Comment: That is what the returned value of `useEffect` is for.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli no idea what your comment means, can you expand on it?

Comment: Right, the `useEffect` callback can return a function, which is use for cleanup. To clean whatever side-effects the actual callback created. So, that is where the `cancel` call should go. Read https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#usage

Answer (score 5):

The docs (I'm looking at 1.9.1 right now) say that you should be able to do:

```js
var fn = () => { console.log('run'); };
var db = _.debounce(fn, 1000);
db();
db.cancel();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

This will do the thing that the OP wants to do (and what I wanted to do). It will not print the console message.

Comment: This works as advertised as of Underscore 1.13.6.

Answer (score 2):

## the Vanilla js variant with cancellable wrap

*Note that this solution doesn't require you to modify an external `debounce` function or to even use an external one. The logic is done in a wrapepr function. Debounce code provided.*

---

The easiest way to allow to cancel an already called function within its debounce period is to call it from a cancelable wrap. Really just add 3 lines of code and an optional condition.

```
const doTheThingAfterADelayCancellable = debounce((filter, abort) => {
  if (abort) return

  // here goes your code...
  // or call the original function here

}, /*debounce delay*/500)


function onFilterChange(filter) {
  let abort = false

  if (filter.length < 3) { // your abort condition
    abort = true
  }

  // doTheThingAfterADelay(filter) // before
  doTheThingAfterADelayCancellable(filter, abort) // new wrapped debounced call
}
```

You cancel it by calling it again with `abort = true`.

The way it works is that it clears the previous timeout fn and sets a new one as it always does, but now with `if (true) return` path.

You can also do it manually from another code...

```
doTheThingAfterADelayCancellable(null, true)
```

...or wrap it and call with `cancelBounce()`

```
function cancelBounce() {
  doTheThingAfterADelayCancellable(null, true)
}
```

> For reference, this is your classic `debounce` function taken from `Underscore`. It remains intact in my example.
>
> ```
> // taken from Underscore.js
> // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
> // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
> // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
> // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
> export function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
>   let timeout
>   return function() {
>     let context = this, args = arguments
>     let later = function() {
>       timeout = null
>       if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
>     }
>     let callNow = immediate && !timeout
>     clearTimeout(timeout)
>     timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
>     if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is used _.mixin to create a _.cancellableDebounce method.  It's nearly identical to the original except for two new lines.

```
_.mixin({
    cancellableDebounce: function(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;

        var later = function() {
          var last = _.now() - timestamp;

          if (last < wait && last >= 0) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
          } else {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) {
              result = func.apply(context, args);
              if (!timeout) context = args = null;
            }
          }
        };

        return function() {
          context = this;
          args = arguments;
          timestamp = _.now();
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
          if (!timeout) timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
          if (callNow) {
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            context = args = null;
          }

          // Return timeout so debounced function can be cancelled
          result = result || {};
          result.timeout = timeout;

          return result;
        };
    }
});
```

USAGE:

```
var thing = function() {
    console.log("hello world");
}

var debouncedThing = _.cancellableDebounce(thing, 1000);
var timeout = debouncedThing().timeout;

clearTimeout(timeout);
```